# Python DocuSign API receiving network error on the sample app

Tags: python, docusignapi

I am running the Python and React [MyUni Education sample app](https://github.com/docusign/sample-app-myuni-python) and have it loading in my localhost3000. When I click on the logins though it is giving me an error:

"Network Error"

I have added config details to the Environment variables via the .env file. I have also received the same error on the other [sample app MySure](https://github.com/docusign/sample-app-mysure-python). So trying to work out what I might be missing.

[image: myuni sample network error]
[image: logging in with Docusigh developer account option brings up redirect error]
[image: continue with a preconfigured login]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the instructions in https://github.com/docusign/sample-app-myuni-python

Specifically, you need to get the command `flask run --port 5001` working correctly before you run "npm start" and you need to update all the required env variables listed in the repo's README.

Comment: Whoops, yes I missed that step. Thank you!

Comment: I just tested and I am getting an "The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign" error even though I configured my Docusign sandbox to include "Redirect URIs of "http://localhost:5001/api" and included the same in my .env file which includes the React environment variables:
REACT_APP_DS_RETURN_URL=http://localhost:3000
REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:5001/api

Comment: If I use the "Continue with preconfigured login" option on the log in, I get a "Request failed with status code 500".

Comment: Just posted these new comments in a fresh post as the network error issue here is solved. So it is more a new issue and I have also added further logs to share too. Re: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63111451/python-docusign-api-receiving-redirect-uri-error-on-the-sample-app

Comment: will help you over there with the other issue. You are on the right track!