# Python DocuSign API receiving redirect URI error on the sample app

Tags: python, docusignapi

I am running the Python and React MyUni Education sample app and have it loading in my localhost3000. When I click on the logins though it is giving me redirect error.

I created a new Docusign integration key in case there was something incorrectly configured in my previous set up, but the error remains the same:
"The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign" error

[image: redirect URI]
[image: redirect URI setting in Docusign sandbox]

Docusign sandbox configured with:
Redirect URIs "http://localhost:5001/api"

.env file I believe has the right environment variables set but please let me know if I am missing anything.

```
# Configuration file for the example
DS_CLIENT_ID=blank
DS_CLIENT_SECRET=blank
DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID=blank
DS_TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID=false
DS_PAYMENT_GATEWAY_ID=blank
DS_PAYMENT_GATEWAY_NAME=Stripe
DS_PAYMENT_GATEWAY_DISPLAY_NAME=Stripe
DS_PRIVATE_KEY=blank

# React environment variables
**REACT_APP_DS_RETURN_URL=http://localhost:3000
REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:5001/api**
REACT_APP_DS_AUTH_SERVER=https://account-d.docusign.com

# Demo Docusign API URL
REACT_APP_DS_DEMO_SERVER=https://demo.docusign.net
REACT_APP_DS_CLICKWRAP_URL=//demo.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js
```

I believe it is affecting the JWT, as when I selected the "continue with a preconfigured login" I received a "Request failed with status code 500" error as well. Logs from that below.
[image: status code 500]

PS C:\Users\windowsuser\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\sample-app-myuni> flask run --port 5001

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2020 16:13:20] "GET /api/get_status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2020 16:13:51] "GET /api/code_grant_auth HTTP/1.1" 401 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2020 16:14:03] "OPTIONS /api/jwt_auth HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2020-07-27 16:14:04,237] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/jwt_auth [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\decorator.py", line 128, in wrapped_function
    resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\windowsuser\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\sample-app-myuni\app\api\auth.py", line 43, in jwt_auth
    DsClient.update_token()
  File "C:\Users\windowsuser\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\sample-app-myuni\app\ds_client.py", line 36, in update_token
    client.request_jwt_user_token(DsConfig.client_id(),
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\client\api_client.py", line 679, in request_jwt_user_token
    raise ArgumentException("Private key not supplied or is invalid!")
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\client\api_exception.py", line 51, in __init__
    super(Exception).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not str
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2020 16:14:04] "POST /api/jwt_auth HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2020 16:18:14] "GET /api/code_grant_auth HTTP/1.1" 401 -
```

Comment: Docusign Integration key setting and .env setting is set to http://localhost:5001/api (HTTP and not HTTPS) so not thinking that would be the issue here. Wondering what else could be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration key settings must match exactly
I think what you can check the URL where you get this error, it has first the IK which you created (GUID value starting with 61C9) then it has the redirectUri. It is URI encoded, but you can figure it out and make sure the same exact matching URI is set in the IK settings in the DocuSign Developer account.
I think it's the localhost:3000 for the front-end and not the localhost:5001 for the back-end and maybe there's an endpoint under there, just check and confirm and add it, wait 30 seconds and try again.

Comment: Okay, I just checked. It looks like it is showing a different redirect URL to the one I set in the Developer portal. https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20click.manage&client_id=61c9a7ec-84ec-BLUR&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&state=

Comment: ok, happy to help. If you were able to get it working - can you mark this as answered?

Comment: we may need to improve our documentation

Comment: I think we are almost there. I managed to get the prompt for permission once. But it seems to have been broken for now. Can you please help me check the IK is correct? 61c9a7ec-84ec-4fa0-88b6-55bf9f0780a1. As I'm getting some "User does not have access to account" messages in my Powershell window for Flask.

Comment: I added http://localhost:3000/ and http://localhost:3000/callback and it triggered it and am just testing which one it needs to continue to work.

Comment: After authenticating okay that one time, I received this page and it redirected back to the http://localhost:3000.

Comment: Here is the link it sent me to for a second (shortened link for this comment box) http://localhost:3000/callback?code=eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQoAAAABAAYABwAAxdgOaDLYSAgAAFFfVmgy2EgCAPu-

Comment: ok, I suspect you didn't set DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID correctly. It has to be the GUID for your user, not account and you can find it in the same screen in the settings where you configure the IK at the top

Comment: Okay, I have set it to another user's GUID in my sandbox organisation so you might be right now. I will set it to my own account's GUID.

Comment: `127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020 04:28:01] "POST /api/callback HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020 04:28:12] "GET /api/code_grant_auth HTTP/1.1" 401 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020 04:28:13] "GET /api/get_status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020 04:28:13] "OPTIONS /api/callback HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2020-07-28 04:28:14,805] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/callback [POST] Exception: User does not have access to account ACCOUNTNO 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020 04:28:14] "POST /api/callback HTTP/1.1" 500 -`

Comment: Not too sure why, but I'm getting mixed errors on the logs. I suspect it has something to do with my callback URIs. Can I please check which localhost I should be setting as the callback?

Comment: the issue is that the GUID must correspond to the user that consented. I would suggest you not use the "preconfigured account" with JWT but try Auth Code Grant with your own account. That should be easier for you.

Comment: Okay, I think I know what you mean. Meaning use only the "Log in with your DocuSign developer account" (which will use Auth Code Grant) option to log in, rather than the "Continue with a preconfigured login" (which will use JWT).

Comment: I am actually getting the errors when using "Log in with your DocuSign developer account".    The other option: "Continue with a preconfigured login" option continues to give the "Request failed with status code 500" but we can ignore that one for now as I'm looking to get just one of the login options to work.

Comment: When I click on "Log in with your DocuSign developer account" it lets me try log into Docusign the first time, but then takes me to http://localhost:3000/callback?code=eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU. Then each time I click on "Log in with your DocuSign developer account" it redirects me back to http://localhost:3000/. Not logged in.

Comment: Logs in the Powershell repeat the following: `Exception:

User does not have access to account< accountno>


127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020 04:59:10] "POST /api/callback HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020 04:59:32] "GET /api/code_grant_auth HTTP/1.1" 401 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020 04:59:33] "GET /api/get_status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020 04:59:33] "OPTIONS /api/callback HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: There is this line in the log there that might be helpful `File "C:\Users\windowsuser\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\sample-app-myuni\app\ds_client.py", line 83, in _get_account_info raise Exception(f'\n\nUser does not have access to account {target}\n\n') Exception: User does not have access to account <accountno> 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2020 04:59:34] "POST /api/callback HTTP/1.1" 500 -`

Comment: ok, this error indicates that the wrong user was supplied. I again wonder about which authentication you're using. This error usually comes with the  DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID  is incorrect and shouldn't show for using your own account.

Comment: I would recommend you try to use an incognito browser. Cookies in the browser are used to remember how you did it before and they may cause you to not be able to log in the way you want to.

Comment: I was testing it in Firefox and Chrome Incognito last night, just tested again and it still seems to have this "HTTP/1.0 401 UNAUTHORIZED" error. To be clear as well, I am using the "User ID" from the https://admindemo.docusign.com/api-integrator-key page as my "DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID/ API username" setting in the .env.

Comment: Okay I just managed to get it working. I added http://localhost:5001/api/callback redirect URL after seeing this endpoint before called in during the process. I believe it has solved the problem. I will do more testing to confirm.

Comment: Tested this with mysure app and it worked. So adding details in the answer so it's easier to see for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Okay just tested this in MySure app. Adding the following will allow the log in function to work as expected.
http://localhost:5001/api/callback
http://localhost:3000/callback
http://localhost:3000/

[image: mysure logged in]

[image: redirect settings]

Comment: would love to hear suggestions on how to improve documentation to help developers figure this out quicker/easier.

Comment: Thanks Inbar, probably some clarity around the authentication options and the ways it is triggered within the web app (i.e. "Log in with your DocuSign developer account"). Specifically details on the expected workflow would be helpful, as for a newbie like myself who just getting familiar with the Docusign APIs, I'm still learning about the workflows and outputs to expect.